# Ubuntu WSL becomes completely unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, gcc, gnu

I am trying to use Ubuntu WSL to build the GNU GCC 9.3.0 toolchain, and thought I managed to do do this, but then I couldn't actually use it as a kit in VSCode. I then assumed I did something wrong, and tried to delete the git repo, and the result from compiling, and do it again.

I have already downloaded all dependencies (I think), so that it fully ran everything without saying it encountered an error. But if you are knowledgeable about the compilation of the toolchain, and using WSL to do it, help on what exactly should be downloaded with `sudo apt-get install` would be greatly appreciated!

I run:

```
cd /mnt/c/dev
git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
git checkout releases/gcc-9.3.0
cd gcc
./configure --prefix=/mnt/c/dev/gcc-9.3 --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j20
make install
```

Very often, it simply freezes, and refuse to function again until I restart. When it freeze, it simply doesn't output any text, and instead just shows my input. When I press `Ctrl+C`, it also just show `^C`.

I thought maybe this means that it is running, but giving it lots of time it still is stuck like this. It mainly happens during the configure or the make. When it has been frozen, it is frozen permanently. New windows of it also is frozen. Task manager -> termination -> Still frozen.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:
Added what I have installed by looking at `history`;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gmp
sudo apt-get install libdevel
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo apt install libgmp-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc-12-dev
apt-get install -y build-essential python3 xorriso genext2fs mtools gnu-efi git automake autoconf wget libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev flex bison texinfo dosfstools
apt-get install -y build-essential python3 xorriso genext2fs mtools gnu-efi git automake autoconf wget libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev flex bison texinfo dosfstools
sudo apt install libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

I added those that I think probably did install successfully. Might be some that weren't actually packages, but that would probably be 1-2 max.

Also in the GNU gcc git I use `./contrib/download_prerequisites`.

[I'm ran the commands below]

Changed it to run in the home directory `~` with the commands now instead being;

```
cd ~
mkdir dev
cd dev
git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git
cd gcc
git checkout releases/gcc-9.3.0
cd ..
mkdir gcc-9.3.0
cd gcc-9.3.0
./../gcc/configure --prefix=$HOME/dev/gcc-9.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
make -j20
make install
```

`--disable-multilib`: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status configure: error: I suspect your system does not have 32-bit development libraries (libc and headers). If you have them, rerun configure with --enable-multilib. If you do not have them, and want to build a 64-bit-only compiler, rerun configure with --disable-multilib.`

On a seperate pc I didn't get this issue, and I thought I downloaded the same packages, and also encountered the same freeze effect. So I just use `--disable-multilib` assuming it isn't the issue.

Also somewhat unrelated to the freezing, the toolchain is now downloaded in `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\~\dev\gcc-9.3.0\bin`, but after adding that to path I still don't find the kit in VS Code... What might be the issue? I do get msgs after doing `make install` informing me that I have not linked libraries, and that I need to use either `libtool` or `-LLIBDIR`.

❯ wsl -l -v

- NAME      STATE           VERSION
- Ubuntu    Running         2

❯ wsl --version

WSL-versjon: 1.2.5.0
Kjerneversjon: 5.15.90.1
WSLg-versjon: 1.0.51
MSRDC-versjon: 1.2.3770
Direct3D-versjon: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore-versjon: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows-versjon: 10.0.19045.2846

Comment: Can you check your shell history and find the exact dependencies that you installed?  To try to reproduce, I'll need to know what you have in place.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I recommend trying this in your home directory, rather than in `/mnt/c`.  That *may* solve the problem, but your comment that *"New windows of it also is frozen"* has me concerned that the issue might not be quite that easy.

Comment: I have unfortunately not had time to try this today, but will try this at the first opportunity. Why does this matter though (curiosity)?

Comment: It may not matter (or we might get lucky), but the Windows drive is accessed as a network filesystem (Plan 9) from WSL2, and there are permissions, file locking, and performance differences between that drive and the virtual Ext4 filesystem.  The gcc build process likely assumes a POSIX compliant filesystem.  99.9% of the time, it doesn't matter, but the gcc build is pretty complex.  At the very least, given the performance difference, trying it under `~` will allow it to "fail faster".

Comment: This was a gazillion times faster wow! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: When I just close the ubuntu window, it doesnt close all processes that I see in the task manager, and when I turned some of, a newer ubuntu window suddenly worked again for a brief moment before becoming useless again.

Comment: Does `wsl.exe --version` return version info, or just the help text?

Comment: In Powershell running `wsl.exe --version`: "Invalid command line option: --version"

Comment: Ok, that gives us something to try at least.  You are on a *much* older WSL release (about 18 months behind) if `wsl --version` doesn't work.  Try installing WSL from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  That should bring you up to the latest version.  Again, we could get lucky and find that whatever issue you are seeing has been fixed.

Comment: And one other question -- Can you add the output of `wsl -l -v` to your question?  Thanks!

Comment: <3>WSL (533) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate Z:\usr\bin

Comment: Is that when starting WSL after updating?  That should just mean that there's an old directory still hanging around in your Windows `PATH`.  Under the Start menu in Windows, search for *"Edit the environment variables"*, then select the *Environment variables* button.  Double-click the `Path` in both System and User sections.  You'll probably find `Z:\usr\bin` there, which most likely doesn't exist.  Remove it, and the WSL error should go away

Comment: Worked after doing that, edited question!

Comment: You should write up your own answer based on the information that @NotTheDr01ds gave you coupled with your own experience.  We don't need the points but you do if you want to play here.  Wait 1 day, accept your own answer (if it is still the best one that is).  If you write a CLEAN, CONCISE ANSWER, people will upvote you and you will get even more points.

Comment: When you say that it worked, do you mean that WSL started, or do you mean that the `gcc` build is now working?

Comment: I'm not after points, just upvote those who comment, as they are trying to help me, and I appreciate it! Will write an answer with what works for now, even though it might not have fixed anything... :P @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: I have been able to start WSL, but when it freezes, it freezes and doesn't respond at all. For now, though, doing as I will write in an answer below, I haven't encountered the freezing in a long time. Also finished building, so that also works. Sorry for the lack of clarity. @NotTheDr01ds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it *seems* like I fixed the issue by;

1. Reinstalling
2. Removing any path variables that use a path to the Linux subsystem (`Z:\`)
3. Using Powershell and `wsl` command instead of running the Ubuntu app
4. Installing the libraries
5. Moving into the Linux subsystem home directory (Bonus: Significantly faster than working in the normal Windows drives. e.g.: `/c/dev/...`)
6. Doing the whole GCC build process there

The process for those who may wanna replicate it or encounter the same issue.

1. Reinstalling

Remove Linux subsystem:
https://pureinfotech.com/remove-linux-distro-wsl/

Install Linux subsystem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

The second installation link is to update to WSL 2 and set it as the default version.

2. Removing any path variables that use a path to the Linux subsystem (`Z:\`)

Windows -> Edit the environment variables -> Check user & system path for any entries that use the `Z:\` drive. There might be another drive letter for your subsystem instead, which I believe can be checked by going into the explorer -> "This PC" and scrolling down.

3. Using Powershell and `wsl` command instead of running the Ubuntu app

Open Powershell and write `wsl`, and press enter to go use WSL in that Powershell instance. Can go back to Powershell by writing `exit`.

4. Installing the libraries
5. Moving into the Linux subsystem home directory (Bonus: Significantly faster than working in the normal Windows drives. e.g.: `/c/dev/...`)
6. Doing the whole GCC build process there

Did all of this a lot of times, and this resulted in me creating a script for it;

Save it as `scriptName.sh`, use `chmod +x /path/to/scriptName.sh` to let you run the script, and then run it. It can be run from anywhere with `/path/to/scriptName.sh`; if it is in the current directory, you can do `./scriptName.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Give permissions:
# chmod +x /path/to/scriptName.sh
# Run:
# /path/to/scriptName.sh OR cd /path/to/; ./scriptName.sh

# Download packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get make -y
sudo apt-get install gcc -y                 # not cross
sudo apt-get install g++ -y
sudo apt-get install make -y
sudo apt-get install bison -y
sudo apt-get install flex -y
sudo apt-get install gawk -y
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev libgmpv4 -y
sudo apt-get install libmpfrc++-dev libmpfr-dev libmpfr-doc libmpfr4 libmpfr4-dbg -y
sudo apt-get install mpc libmpc-dev -y
sudo apt-get install texinfo -y            # optional
sudo apt-get install libcloog-isl-dev -y   # optional
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel -y
sudo apt-get -y install gcc-multilib libc6-i386 -y
sudo apt-get install libz-dev -y

printf "\n\n\n\nFinished downloading packages (except for prerequisites)\n\n\n\n"

# Git repo copy and checkout

cd $HOME

mkdir dev

cd dev

printf "\n\n\n\nMoved into dev\n\n\n\n"

sudo rm -r gcc

git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git

cd gcc

git checkout releases/gcc-9.3.0

printf "\n\n\n\nMoved into gcc\n\n\n\n"

# Build

./contrib/download_prerequisites

printf "\n\n\n\nFinished downloading prerequisites\n\n\n\n"

./configure                                            \
    --prefix=/usr/                                     \
    --disable-multilib                                 \
    --with-system-zlib                                 \
    --enable-languages=c,c++

make -j$(nproc)

printf "\n\n\n\nFinished make\n\n\n\n"

sudo make install -j$(nproc)

printf "\n\n\n\nFinished make install\n\n\n\n"
```

A note for the script is that `sudo rm -r gcc` and `git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git` can be commented out to reduce the execution time by a lot. I had several iterations of the script and sometimes had issues with stuff inside `/gcc/` already was created, and therefore, changes to, for example, the configure sometimes messed up. Maybe it was just me doing it wrong, but I let it stay in to ensure it works.

It hasn't frozen but runs for a few hours at a time. It might not have fixed the issue, but since it works, it is a solution for now.